# trouble loading an ESRI ArcGrid export file (e00) in R

Tags: r, geospatial, raster

I am trying to load an ESRI ArcGrid export file into R. The file is located at- ftp://ftp.epa.gov/castnet/tdep/grids/n_tw/n_tw-2013.zip. The documentation for this file states, "Gridded data of the above variables are available in compressed ESRI ArcGRID export files" and not much else. Link to documentation  [here](ftp://ftp.epa.gov/castnet/tdep/Total_Deposition_Documentation_current.pdf). My major problem is that this is an `e00` file, an old output format of Arc.

The most straightforward way to load a raster normally (if this wasn't an `e00` file) would be:

```
require(raster)
require(rgdal)    
test <- raster('/path/to/n_tw-2013.e00')
```

However, you will receive the error: `n_tw-2013.e00 not recognised as a supported file format.`.

The `RArcInfo` package claims to be able to convert `.e00` files into more useful Arc/Info binary coverage. To do this:

```
require(RArcInfo)
#first argument is the path to the e00 file, and the second argument is the new directory to create
e00toavc('/path/to/n_tw-2013.e00','/path/to/test1')
```

When I run this command it prints `NULL`, and creates two directories, `test1`, and `info`, however, both are empty. I'm not sure whats going wrong here. Any advice on how to get this loaded into R as a raster so I can extract data to my specific lat/long would be greatly appreciated.

Output of `sessionInfo` pasted here:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgdal_1.2-5  raster_2.5-8 sp_1.2-4    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2     Rcpp_0.12.3     grid_3.2.2      lattice_0.20-33
```

Comment: see [RArchInfo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RArcInfo/index.html) package  for reading`.e00` files in r

Comment: @ImranAli see updated question. The `RArcInfo` package still is not solving my problem for some reason.

Comment: checkout [this GIS question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222525/trouble-loading-an-esri-arcgrid-export-file-e00-in-r)

Comment: I can read it using `raster()`. Maybe update the packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem reading in the file using `rgdal 1.2-3` and `raster 2.5-8`:

```
require(raster)
require(rgdal)   
test <- raster('n_tw-2013.e00')
test
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 775, 1440, 1116000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 4134.354, 4134.354  (x, y)
extent      : -2950369, 3003101, 115686.8, 3319811  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=0 +lat_2=29.5 +lat_0=45.5 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=-96 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : /Users/Martin/Desktop/n_tw-2013.e00 
names       : n_tw.2013 
values      : 0.8068619, 70.83445  (min, max)
```

---

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.12.2 (Sierra)

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.5-8 sp_1.2-3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7       plotly_4.5.2      magrittr_1.5      munsell_0.4.3     colorspace_1.2-7 
 [6] viridisLite_0.1.3 lattice_0.20-34   R6_2.2.0          httr_1.2.1        plyr_1.8.4       
[11] dplyr_0.5.0       tools_3.3.1       rgdal_1.2-3       grid_3.3.1        gtable_0.2.0     
[16] DBI_0.5-1         htmltools_0.3.5   lazyeval_0.2.0    assertthat_0.1    digest_0.6.10    
[21] tibble_1.2        purrr_0.2.2       ggplot2_2.2.0     tidyr_0.6.0       base64enc_0.1-3  
[26] htmlwidgets_0.8   scales_0.4.1      jsonlite_1.1
```

Comment: strange, I just updated both `raster` and `rgdal`, but this still does not work for me...

Comment: I added my sessionInfo. Maybe restart R so you have a clean environment.

Comment: Thanks for this. You prompted me to test this on my local machine where it did work with just the call to `raster`. No luck updating my packages or restarting R, but this definitely pushed me further. Will award the bounty as soon as I can.

Comment: I am still interested in why it does not work. What OS are you using on the machine that does not like this snippet?

Comment: sessionInfo pasted into thread.

Comment: Could you try `raster('n_tw-2013.e00', native = T)` on Debian? And maybe rename the file so it does not contain hyphen or an underscore. Just to be sure :)

Comment: same problem, `not recognised as a supported file format. Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131428/discussion-between-martin-schmelzer-and-colin).

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `readGDAL` from `library(rgdal)`

In your example should work:

```
n_tw_2013 <- readGDAL("path/to/the/file/n_tw-2013.e00")
```